# How can I check whether dynamically-created Checkboxes are checked (VB.NET)?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, user-controls, dynamically-generated

I have a start on looping through dynamically-created Checkboxes:

```
For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf cntrl Is CheckBox Then
        If (cntrl As CheckBox).Checked Then
            'Do Something
        End If
    End If
Next
```

...but I don't know what I need instead of this line:

```
If (cntrl As CheckBox).Checked Then
```

...which was just a guess and which does not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is :

```
If DirectCast(cntrl, CheckBox).Checked = True Then
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [LInQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) would save you some lines of code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim myList as New List(Of CheckBox)
    For Each cbox As CheckBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox).Where(Function(cb) cb.Checked)
        myList.Add(cbox)
    Next
    Msgbox(String.Format("{0} checkboxes were checked!", myList.Count))
End Sub
```

Comment: I have this in my code, too, but I am a VB newbie; does a "For Each" really need a "Next"? It seems redundant/superfluous.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, yes, because it defines an iterating block. It will repeat the instructions between `For Each ...` and `Next` as many times as many items you have in your enumeration. After that, it will follow running any statements placed after `Next` in a simple sequence

Comment: ISTM that "foreach" should be sufficient to indicate that you are looping through the entire collection. Having both a "foreach" and "next" seems akin to wearing both belt AND suspenders.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, without `Next`, how does you tell your code where ends the sequence of statements you want to repeat and start a regular, non-repeating, sequence of code?

Comment: After all the Checkboxes in Me.Controls have been iterated over.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, I edited my code for you to see what I am trying to explain: iterated statements must be enclosed. The use of the word `Next` may be a quirk of VB, but the trailing enclosure is not: in C# and other languages, you will define your iteration, then put the iterating statements between curly braces (`{...}`). Omit `Next` in VB would be the same as omitting the closing brace `}` in C#, JS, PHP, etc.

Comment: OK, cool [beans,enough]; thanks! I would have marked yours as the answer, except for my Robin Hood method of giving it to the cat with the fewest points, where possible.

Comment: No problem, because @D.Hislop 's answer is technically super correct and answers *exactly* what you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
Dim con As Checkbox
For Each con In Me.Controls
   If con.Checked = True
      'Do Something
   End If
Next
```